# Refactor -> Extract Interface does nothing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2022
I'm trying to extract an interface
Under
Edit , Refactor , Extract Interface

But no Interface is generated nothing happens. I've tried it on multiple boxes.
Any ideas?
thx

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing the same thing. I've tried only checking the minimum items to include and still nothing happens. No output, no message, nothing. VS2022 leave a lot to be desired IMAO. But, hey, they've done some work on the UI ...